# How to have a terminal emulator send click drag messages?

Tags: java, vim, terminal, emulation, xterm

I'm an amateur programmer who's interested in adding a click-drag method to the vt320 terminal emulator at http://javassh.org/download/source/de/mud/terminal/vt320.html. I'm looking through the source for mouse press function and came upon this:

```
byte b[] = new byte[6];
b[0] = 27;
b[1] = (byte) '[';
b[2] = (byte) 'M';
b[3] = (byte) mousecode;
b[4] = (byte) (0x20 + x + 1);
b[5] = (byte) (0x20 + y + 1);

write(b); // FIXME: writeSpecial here
```

Where x and y are the character positions and mousecode has to do with the mouse button. Seems fairly straightfoward to add a mouse drag message. Can anyone point me in the direction of what the bytes should be? Or am I missing a very obvious roadblock? I'm mostly interested in sending click-drag to vim, running on Connectbot for android. Seems like it would be a really sweet thing to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal mouse mode is perhaps best described by xterm's [ctlseqs](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) document. In summary, when the terminal is in one of the mouse reporting modes, it sends events in the form

CSI M Ps Px Py

Where CSI is either the single C1 CSI control (`0x9b`) or the two-byte sequence ESC (`0x1b`) [.

Ps, Px and Py encode the "status", x and y coordinate, as a single byte which is offset by `0x20` to ensure it is a GL printable and not a C0 control byte. Px and Py should be obvious. Ps is a bitmask containing the following fields:

- Bits 0 to 1 encode the button number; `0` to `2` for buttons 1 to 3, or `3` for a release (it does not encode which button was released)
- Bit 2 is set if the `Shift` modifier is held (though most terminals will capture mouse internally and not report it to applications in this condition)
- Bit 3 is set if the `Alt` modifier is held
- Bit 4 is set if the `Ctrl` modifier is held
- Bit 5 is set if the mouse event is a drag motion rather than a press.
- Bit 6 is set to extend the mouse button range to buttons 4 and 5, used for the scroll wheel.

There are three mouse modes that use this reporting, all set by DECSM; Set DEC private mode (CSI ? Pn h):

- Mode 1000 reports mouse press and release events only
- Mode 1002 reports mouse press, release, and motion when a button is held (drag)
- Mode 1003 reports mouse press, release, and motion events even without a button held

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I was looking for... I'm going to play around with just sending the mouse signals to see if it works, not really sure what to do with the DECSM codes ...